# Which technology succeeded MSXML?

Tags: windows

According to Wikipedia, MSXML is now a legacy technology.
Is there a technology that has since surpassed it in capability?

Comment: Hmm, well if you're doing .NET development then `System.Xml` is pretty powerful stuff.  Lots of open source alternatives out there too: https://www.google.com/search?q=open+source+xml+parser+windows